# how to validate custom fields in phpfox

Tags: phpfox

- i have created few custom fields in registration form .
- And i want to validate those  field .
- Any help will be apriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you created a plug-in? There are Hooks in the user.add controller and the user.process service that would help you

Answer (score 0):

You can validate custom fields from admin where you create custom fields
there an option to set them required or not required.

Comment: But how create custom rule to check?